# try to find a proper way of doing autocomplete using input in angular 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular2-template

**problem**

Here is my autocomplete component when we type something it gets relevant result as I accept but the difficulty is that I use this **autocomplete input** many time in a form and also the data are getting through web service.

Currently, I think is there any way to make the code more compact and dynamic as possible so it can be used many time as we want in a compact way?

```
  **here my html**   
     <input id="country" type="text" class="validate filter-input" [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)=filter($event) (blur)="handleBlur()">
            <div class="suggestions" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
              <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of filteredList;let idx = index" [class.complete-selected]="idx == selectedIdx"
                    (mousedown)="select($event,item)">
                  {{item}}
                </li>
              </ul>
```

**Here is my logic in component**

```
 getCityList(){
    this.cityService.getCity()
      .subscribe(
        city => this.onCityListSuccess(city),
        error => this.onCityListError(error));
  }

  onCityListSuccess(result: any) {
    this.cityList=result.city;
    console.log(this.cityList);
  }

  onCityListError(error: any) {
    this.errorService.message(error);
  }

  public query = '';
  public countries:any=[];
  filteredList:any =[];
  elementRef:any;
  selectedIdx: number;
  a:any[];
  filter(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    if (this.query !== "") {
      this.countries=this.cityList;
     this.filteredList = this.countries.filter(function (el:any) {
        return (el.toLowerCase().substr(0,this.query.length) === this.query.toLowerCase()) == true;
      }.bind(this));
      if (event.code == "ArrowDown" && this.selectedIdx < this.filteredList.length) {
        this.selectedIdx++;
      } else if (event.code == "ArrowUp" && this.selectedIdx > 0) {
        this.selectedIdx--;
      }
    } else {
      this.filteredList = [];
    }
  }

  select(event:any,item:any) {
    this.query = item;

    this.filteredList = [];
    this.selectedIdx = -1;
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  handleBlur() {
    if (this.selectedIdx > -1) {
      this.query = this.filteredList[this.selectedIdx];
    }
    this.filteredList = [];
    this.selectedIdx = -1;
  }

  handleClick(event:any) {
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
    var inside = false;
    do {
      if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
        inside = true;
      }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
    } while (clickedComponent);
    if (!inside){
      this.filteredList = [];
    }
    this.selectedIdx = -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom directive for autocomplete.Like below

```
var app  = angular.module('YourModule',[]);
app.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
 };
});
```